# 'ls -l' in groovy

Tags: unix, groovy

I need to display name, size, date of files using `ls -l` unix command in groovy .

How can we run `ls -l` in groovy to view info ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
"ls -l".execute().text
```

Should do it

Answer (score 6):

```
def list = 'ls -l'.execute().text
list.eachLine{
    // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind restricting yourself to the file properties that Java knows about, you can do this in a more portable, flexible, secure and efficient way using methods of the File class.

```
File dir = new File(".")
dir.eachFile { f ->
   println "${f} ${f.size()} ${new Date(f.lastModified())}"
}
```

Check both the GroovyDocs and the JavaDocs for File to see all the ways you can filter files, and all the properties you have access to.

Of course you could have any code in that block, replacing println.

In the Perl world, we learned that invoking shell commands was usually to be avoided, when native Perl was an option. This is even more true in Groovy, I'd argue. Of course, you might have a special requirement, where you need the exact output 'ls -l' would produce.

Comment: yes my requirement is to produce exact output. But i would like to consider your comment. my requirement may change now . thanks for the comment

Comment: For any kind of professional for-pay development, this solution should be heavily favored since it is platform independent, faster and more reliable.  For your own scripts, I'd say that this is still easier to deal with but sometimes when scripting you just want to get stuff done.